# Composing a Polly Policy with user feedback

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic

There are several policy's that need to be the same throughout my code. For example:

```
var myIOProblems = Policy
  .Handle<IOException>()
  .WaitAndRetryForever(i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

Then I'll have some code that will do the work:

```
myIOProblems
    .Execute(() => otherPath.CopyTo(otherPathPart.FullName));
```

This works great, and I can litter the latter statements all over my code, change the behavior in one central place, and it all seems to work.

But in some places I need to provide the user/framework some feedback that problems are occurring. I can write a new policy:

```
Policy
    .Handle<IOException>()
    .WaitAndRetryForever(i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), (e, t, c) =>
    {
        count++;
        statusUpdate.PCall($"Copying {otherPath.Name}: {other.Name} -> {Name} (retry ({count}): {e.Message})");
    })
    .Execute(() => otherPath.CopyTo(otherPathPart.FullName));
```

But now I've lost the ability to re-use common code. What I'd really like to be able to write is something like the following:

```
myIOProblems
    .OnRetry(e => statusUpdate.PCall($"Error ({e.Message}), retrying"))
    .Execute(() => otherPath.CopyTo(otherPathPart.FullName));
```

Or something similar to that. I may be overlooking something in the library, in which case I apologize!

Comment: Consider using `Execute()` overloads taking context data.  You can use the same common policy, but supply different context data to `Execute()` at different call locations.  The `onRetry` delegate receives this `Context` as a parameter, and can fork its behaviour accordingly.

Comment: OnRetry above is something I made up - to demonstrate what I'd like to do. But, yeah, with the context, that will be fed to WaitAndRetryForever, and perhaps I can have a special functor in there that gets executed...

Comment: I was referring to the `onRetry` delegate built into all Polly retry policies, rather than your made up `.OnRetry()`.  In your first posted code example, the code `(e, t, c) => { ... }` is the `onRetry` delegate.  The `c` input parameter you have there is the `Context`.  This parameter `c` will be passed any context data you pass into an `Execute()` overload taking context data.  So, you can use the same common policy, but vary `onRetry` behaviour by passing different context data to `Execute()` at different call locations.

Comment: Do you want to update the caller each and every time when a retry attempt occur or only when all retry attempts have failed?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your policy in a factory class and the getter function will optionally receive the onRetry callback:

```
public class PolicyFactory
{
    public static Policy GetMyPolicy(Action<Exception, TimeSpan, Context> onRetry = null)
    {
        return Policy
            .Handle<IOException>()
            .WaitAndRetryForever(i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), onRetry);
    }
}
```